# Store barcodes from excel in database and assign next not used to a SKU when called

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have purchased some barcodes from GS1 and we have the non used to an excel file.

We transfered to Shopify from Magento and we stopped autogenerating barcodes(they have implemented a custom solution for this) when creating new products.

I know i can save them to a database(mongodb preferably) the problem is how i can get the next not used from that database everytime i create a new product?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SKU for each product is unique, and no SKU will be assigned multiple barcodes, store the assigned sku in the document with each barcode, with a value of `null`, zero, or `""` to indicate an unused barcode.

To assign a barcode to a sku, use update with a filter for the "unused" value, and set the sku field:

```
db.collection.updateOne({sku:null},{$set:{sku:newSKU}})
```

Any time you need the barcode for a specific SKU, you can query with

```
db.collection.find({sku:SKUtofind})
```